# Azure DocumentDB vs Blob Storage for multiple PDF files per user

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-identity, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I am developing my first application as a learning project doing absolutely everything:

- Client frontend (angular)
- Backend (OWIN Self Host, ASP.NET Web Api 2)
- Database and hosting (Azure deployment)

Its been a learning process so far and I have in my application accomplished login/register authorization using tokens but am  storing my user credentials using the Identity framework and a Azure SQL DB (stored under dbo.AspNetUsers table that was created for me).

To go along with my users table I wish to have a table to actually store the metadata that is associated with my users, in my applications case:

> - Credit Card Information
> - PDF files (in BLOB format, but multiple files associated with each account) These BLOB files are created when they upload a PDF and
>     turned back into a PDF later when they download them.

I see on the Azure Portal there is a Document NoSQL Database as well as BLOB storage. I wish to know if maybe I can add credit card information to my already existing AspNetUsers tables which could simplify me only having to deal with storing the PDF data in a seperate table by itself.

I am also unsure the structure of the table since one user can have many PDF files. My amateur knowledge thought that maybe having a Key Value database instead could be better in the format of:

```
  Key-UserName            Value- JSON object of BLOB's with Id's.
```

I feel that for the PDF table on retrieving a BLOB representing a PDF it would not be best to retrieve all of them if I could associate an ID with each entry and figured a JSON object I could add as many fields as I wish to query on, but am unsure.

Obviously this is very premature and I am just looking for resources and experiences rather than a straight answer.

Answer (score 4):

> I wish to know if maybe I can add credit card information to my
>   already existing AspNetUsers tables which could simplify me only
>   having to deal with storing the PDF data in a seperate table by
>   itself.

I'm not sure if you can add a column to this table but practically speaking I would stay away from storing user's credit card information in application database. If possible, I would use a 3rd party payment processor and integrate my solution with that instead of storing credit card information myself (a bit off topic comment, I know :)).

Now coming to your other question about storing PDFs, I would recommend going with Azure Blob Storage over DocumentDB. Some of the reasons I outlined here: [Create a cloud storage app with ASP.NET and Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36248344/create-a-cloud-storage-app-with-asp-net-and-azure). Other reasons I could think of are:

- While it is true that you can store files as attachments with DocumentDB but there's a limit to the size of attachment (last I checked it was 2MB). This limit is 200GB in case of blob storage.
- You can't directly stream attachment contents from DocumentDB. You would first need to fetch the contents in your application and then stream the contents however with blob storage you can directly stream the contents.

As far as solution goes, there are two approaches you can take:

1. **Create an `Attachments` table**. In reality it is a simple table with composite primary key - User Id + Blob Url. Whenever a user uploads a file in blob storage, you get a blob URL. You can then store this along with some other information like file name, uploaded date etc. in that table. This approach would work well if you want to query on the data e.g. order the files in reverse chronological order.
2. **Create a container / user**. In this case, all files uploaded by a user goes in a container. Please see the link above for more details. In this case, when you want to display the files uploaded by a user, you simply list the blobs from the container assigned to that user. However please keep in mind that this approach would work well if the user has uploaded less than 5000 files because one call to list blobs in a container can only return a maximum of 5000 records. Also please note that blob storage is a simple object store and does not have querying capabilities.

Comment: Do you recommend or know of any third party credit card applications that I could securely store their information in? Simply  need to associate a user with their information for payment.

Also I may be misunderstanding, but you mean create an Attachments table in my current Azure SQL DB? So in this you suggest a user having multiple rows in this table one for each blob pointer? I think this makes sense to me.

Thanks for the response!

Comment: For our application we use FastSpring (http://www.fastspring.com) and we're very happy with it. There're many more out there like PayPal etc. `Also I may be misunderstanding, but you mean create an Attachments table in my current Azure SQL DB?` --> That's correct.

Comment: Please, why a composite primary key of User Id + Blob URL? Why not an identity column as the primary key?

Comment: @nmit026 If you're using SQL Database, then I would agree with you. If you're using Azure Tables, then going identity column route will create a problem for you if you want to search for attachments for each user as Azure Tables have limited querying support.

Answer (score 4):

For the credit card info, a simple mapping table in Azure SQL between user ids and CC numbers would suffice, and would allow you to handle 1-to-many relationships between users and credit cards (you don't specify, so perhaps this isn't an issue now... maybe later?).

Regarding the PDFs... DocumentDB is not your ideal solution from a cost or performance standpoint. It's not well-suited for storage and retrieval of binary data like PDFs. In your scenario I would strongly consider using Blob storage to hold the PDF content itself, and map PDFs to users via a mapping table in SQL Azure that associates user ids to blob URIs. If you need to store and query extra metadata for PDFs you can use extra columns in the SQL mapping table. You'll have a bit of burden to synchronize the mappings to blobs as they're created or removed, but it's a fairly common data scenario in the cloud.

Best of luck!